# casperjs jquery return data is null

Tags: jquery, return

I used jquery in casperjs.
but return data is null.

checked code, but I dont know..

html code is....

```
<table id="bd_lst" class="bd_lst">
<tr class="notice">
    <td class="cate">aaaaa</td>
    <td class="title"><a href="11111.html">11111</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="notice">
    <td class="cate">bbbb</td>
    <td class="title"><a href="22222.html">22222</a></td>
</tr>
......................
<tr>
    <td class="cate">cccc</td>
    <td class="title"><a href="aaa.html">3333</a></td> <== i want return data "aaa.html"
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cate">ddddd</td>
    <td class="title"><a href="bbbb.html">4444</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

js code is....

```
var start_link = this.evaluate(function(){ 
    return $("#bd_list tr.notice").last().next().find(".title a").attr("href"); 
});
```

start_link is null..

$("table tr.notice").last().next().find(".title a").attr("href") is return "aaa.html" in html javascript..

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check only the `href` value of the first anchor tag, use this:

```
$('td.title > a').first().attr('href');
```

---

Using casperjs to scrape the sample DOM:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://my-site.com/examples/casperjs/sample.html', function() {
    var start_link = this.evaluate(function(){
        return document.querySelector('td.title > a').getAttribute('href');
    });
    this.echo(start_link);
});

casper.run();
```

---

In the case you want to use jQuery with casperjs, you have to make the jQuery available with the `clientScripts` option like following:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    clientScripts: ['jquery-1.9.1.min.js']
});

casper.start('http://my-site.com/examples/casperjs/sample.html', function() {
    var start_link = this.evaluate(function(){
        return $('td.title > a').first().attr('href');
    });
    this.echo(start_link);
});

casper.run();
```

---

The selector you have used:

```
$("#bd_lst tr.notice").last().next().find(".title a").attr("href");
```

is working fine. You have just commit an error typing the table id : it's `bd_lst` instead of `bd_list`.

Hope it's useful!

Comment: thanks.. your comment. but html code is example. The problem is not a jquery selector, a casperjs evaluate return. my jquery code is working.. too. but not return the value inside casperjs.

Comment: @Kan: ok. You want to use casper for scraping or for testing?

Comment: @Kan: Your evaluate function is working fine. You have just commit a typing error in the table'id: it's `bd_lst` instead of `bd_list`.